# how to make non-normally distributed variables show median (P75-P25) in tableone package

Tags: r, tableone

In tableone package, how to make non-normally distributed variables show `median (P75-P25)`? In the following example, the non-normally distributed variable `bili` is shown as `bili (median [IQR])` corresponding to  `1.40 [0.80, 3.40]`, and I want the result to be
 `1.40 (2.60)`, where `2.60 = 3.40-0.80`.

I don't know how to get the results I want.

```r
library(tableone)
library(survival)# 为了使用pbc数据集
data(pbc)

biomarkers <- c("bili")

myVars <- c("time",  "bili")

tab2 <- CreateTableOne(vars = myVars, data = pbc)

print(tab2, nonnormal = biomarkers)
#>                      
#>                       Overall             
#>   n                       418             
#>   time (mean (SD))    1917.78 (1104.67)   
#>   bili (median [IQR])    1.40 [0.80, 3.40]
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>